# nodejs function declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am declaring a function like so in a file:

```
File1:
    module.exports = {
       function1: function(callback){
          //do some work
       },
    }
```

In another file if i import File1 and call file1.function1 the function runs and I get the result.

Although, if I am in File1 and declare another function:

```
module.exports = {
    function1: function(callback){
          //do some work
    },
    function2: function(callback){
        var result = function1...
    }
}
```

In this case I am getting function1 is not defined.

Why is this happening? shouldn't it be called the someway independent of where the call is being made?

Comment: Those are function expressions, not function declarations.

Comment: Please show us the exact code that produces the error, both of the exports and the import.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to access function1 from the wrong scope. There is no defined "function1" variable in your scope. You only have module.exports.function1

```
const exportObject = {
    function1: function(callback){
          //do some work
    },
    function2: function(callback){
        var result = exportObject.function1... // or this.function1
    }
}

module.exports = exportObject;
```

Should work

UPDATE: a few more examples:

```
function1() {
   // this will be executed by example2
}

var example3 = {
   function1: function () {
      // this will be executed by example3
   }
}
const exportObject = {
    function1: function(callback){
        // This will be executed by example1
    },
    function2: function(callback){
        // example1
        var result = exportObject.function1() // or this.function1()
        // example2
        var result = function1()
        // example3
        var result = example3.function1()
    }
}

module.exports = exportObject;
```

Comment: Ok having it like this works. any more details on why it is like this? i'll accept this answer

Comment: The main issue is semantics. as @user1695032 mentions, `function1` is not visible in the scope of `function2`. You can rewrite this code block in a couple of ways that could work better for you.

Comment: I've updated the answer... if you look at example nr 3... that's what you essentially needed to do to make your code work. The difference is that you  it was a part of the same parent object.

Answer (score 3):

`function1` is not a variable.

It is a property of the object you assigned to `module.exports`.

Compare to this:

```js
var foo = {
  bar: 1
}

console.log(bar);
```

`bar` is a property of `foo`, not a variable in its own right.

You have to treat it as such.

```js
var foo = {
  bar: 1
}

console.log(foo.bar);
```

The same is true of `function1`.

You need to access it as object property:

```
var result = module.exports.function1();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function `module.exports.function1` in File 1, the way you access it in File 1 is by saying `module.exports.function1`. It's a bit long winded. Alternatively, you can create it like this in File 1:

```
 var function1 = function() {...};
 module.exports.function1 = function1;

 function1();
```

You can continue to use `function1` in File 2:

```
 var file1 = require('./file1');
 file1.function1();
```